# Match last string between special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the last string between special characters. I've done for square bracket as `\[(.*)\]$`

But, when I use it on something like `Blah [Hi]How is this[KoTuWa]`. I get the result as `[Hi]How is this[KoTuWa]`.

How do i modify it to get the last stringthat is `KotuWa`.

Also, I would like to generalise to general special characters, instead of just matching the string between square brackets as above.

Thanks,
Sai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
[^[\]]+(?=][^[\]]*$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ypslDQJ5ErtCQtXT)

To extend this to other types of brackets/special chars, say I also wanna match curly braces `{` and double quotes `"`:

```
[^{}"[\]]+(?=["\]}][^{}"[\]]*$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/oErnoonzK8xlJJEB) *(I added the multi-line `/m` only to show multiple examples)*

Comment: Thanks, this seems to fine so far. But how do i extend this easily to the last string between a set of special characters?

Comment: Depends on what "special characters" are to you. Basically you put those in both the negative character classes (the `[^...]` parts you see). And they you replace the first `]` in the lookhead (that's the `(?=...)` part) with a character-class of acceptable end-delimiter characters.

Comment: This seems to be easier just doing something like `\W+([\w\s]+)\W*$`

Comment: @hwnd could be, but your regex considers `_` **not** a special character where most people _would_ consider it a special character. As well with any sentence ending in a regular period `.` the period would be treated as a special character which my gut feeling tells me would not be the intended behavior.

Comment: Definitely at a certain point it makes more sense to say _"these are not special, everything else is"_ rather than _"these characters are special, everything else isn't"_.

Answer (score 0):

You can require that the string between brackets does not contain brackets:

Edit: thanks to funkwurm and jcubic for pointing out an error. Here's the [fixed expression](https://regex101.com/r/wG3mO2/2):

```
\[([^[]+)\][^\[]*$
```

---

If you need to use other separators than brackets, you should:

- replace the `\[` and `\]` with your new separators
- replace the negative character classes with your beginning separator.

For example, assuming you need to use the separators `<>` instead of `[]`, you'd do [this](https://regex101.com/r/wG3mO2/3):

```
<([^<]+)>[^\>]*$
```

Comment: Breaks if there's any character after the `[KoTuWa]` like [here](https://regex101.com/r/aX8yH9/1)

Comment: there can be more characters after the bracketed word like "[foo]bar[baz]quux"

Comment: What was good about the previous expression was that, I could customze the special characters. How do i do so in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
   \[([^\[]*)\]$
```